# In CSS, can I line up heights of inline-blocks?

Tags: css

In CSS, can I line up heights of inline-blocks?

I thought by setting margins to 0 and height to auto, that the block would expand to fit the available space, but it still tightly wraps around the block.

```
.myclass {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1em;
    height: auto;
    border: solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6NQDw/

I would like both boxes to be the same height, but want the div width/heights to be determined by their content, not specifying a width/height in pixels.

Is there some kind of padding/margin/alignment CSS or something like that that I can use?

Comment: What about `vertical-align:top`?

Comment: As another option, if you're using inline-block in order to wrap divs to the next line, you can change to block with float-left, and then you can set the height explicitly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use `display:table-cell;` if you require a pure CSS solution but do take note that it won't work in IE7 (I guess IE6 is by now completely forgotten).

```
.myclass {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1em;
    height: auto;
    border: solid;
}
```

**[Cross browser support for display:table-cell](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell)**

Your best bet for achieving what you need is JavaScript however explicitly setting width of containers with dynamic content is almost always not the right way to solve the issue.

Comment: `inline-block` doesn't work for block elements in IE7 either anyway, so I'm guessing IE7 support is not needed.

Comment: Well sure I am just presenting options.

Comment: table-cell is tempting (is it okay to use outside of a table?), but is there a way to preserve space between the .myclass blocks?  When I switched to table-cell, it collapsed the spacing, and adding margins doesn't seem to get any space between the border lines. http://jsfiddle.net/6NQDw/18/

Comment: @BoltClock `inline-block` doesn't work, but you can create the same effect by making an `inline` element `hasLayout`.  The star hack will work: `zoom:1; *display:inline` will do the same thing in IE6/7 as `inline-block` in sensible browsers.

Comment: @SteveHwan [Use `border-spacing`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/6NQDw/19/) with `display: table-cell`.

Comment: `border-spacing` is the only thing that I can think of now too. Though just in case be sure to set `border-collapse:separate;` because I've seen browsers act strange without using that particular border model and `border-spacing`. Anyway JavaScript still seems the most reasonable solution to this problem if there is no other way to achieve what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: THANK YOU.  Been messing with this for an hour!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Just add `vertical-align:top;`

Example:

```css
.myclass {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1em;
    height: auto;
    border: solid;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="myclass">
        line 1<br />
        line 2<br />
        line 3<br />
    </div>

    <div class="myclass">
        line 1<br />
        line 2<br />
        line 3<br />
        line 4<br />
        line 5<br />
        line 6<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The results gives cells that do not have same height

Comment: @MickaelFM I've tweaked code and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: table-cell;` to make the boxes match each other's height.

Comment: How might I allow the number of items per row to vary?

Answer (score 0):

If you want support for IE7, you cannot use inline-block or table-cell.

Just use float:left to be safe...

otherwise you will land up using a separate css just for IE7.

Comment: I don't think the float achieves the equal heights either.  http://jsfiddle.net/6NQDw/17/

Comment: if you know what to expect inside the two boxes, then you can just add "height" to "myclass". however, if you expect the content inside the boxes can change, then that will be an issue to fix in IE7.

Answer (score -2):

Its easy to add a style sheet for lte ie8, reset your properties to display:block, float:left, and make the total width out of 99% instead of 100%.  This will give you the required functionality all the way back.

Comment: on SO we share code, can you edit your answer so it's scoped to the original posters question?